# How do I get headerFilterStrategy to work with http4?

Tags: apache-camel

I want to use the [headerFilterStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.14.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/HeaderFilterStrategy.html) functionality in [http4](https://camel.apache.org/http4.html) to filter out most headers from a HTTP-request. I want to use the headers later on, after the HTTP-request, so using removeHeaders is not an option.

I figured I'd try with DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy:

```
<bean id="beanHeaderFilter" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy"/>
...
<to uri="http4://localhost:8080/my/path?headerFilterStrategy=#beanHeaderFilter"/>
```

All I get from that is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException. So I tried making my own headerFilterStrategy:

```
public class HeaderFilter implements HeaderFilterStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean applyFilterToCamelHeaders(String s, Object o, Exchange exchange) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean applyFilterToExternalHeaders(String s, Object o, Exchange exchange) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When referencing the HeaderFilter as above I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Using camel 2.14.

Comment: Thank you for giving example how this should work

Answer (score 1):

Aargh, I was paying so much attention to what headers were coming through that I didn't notice what was in the headers. The request I was trying to make was using POST when it should be using GET. It works now. Hopefully this thread will be of some use to somebody in the future :)