# Camel how to bypass request header from entering to http dsl component request?

Tags: http, apache-camel, query-string

I'm having a following problem with camel http requests. I would want to preserve a value of url query string parameter without passing it to another http request that needs to be done on the route. The value is needed after the http request to external api to process the data. Below is a clarification of the problem:

```
rest("/api")//We get requests as /camel/api?param1=xyz...
    .get()
        .route()
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
        .setHeader("Accept-Encoding", constant("gzip"))
        .setHeader("Accept", constant("*/*"))
        .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI)//Remove this
        //How do I prevent the {header.param1} from being passed to the following http request but still be able to use it after the request on the route?
        .to("https://someapi.org/api/...")
        //To process the result, we need the original {header.param1} value from the request to this /camel/api endpoint

    .endRest();
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get headerFilterStrategy to work with http4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897141/how-do-i-get-headerfilterstrategy-to-work-with-http4)

Comment: Actually yes, that answers it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you receive parameters that are **only needed in the current route** and should not be passed on to any other endpoints, you can also copy them over [to Exchange properties](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/setProperty-eip.html) and [delete the headers](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/removeHeader-eip.html).

In contrast to message headers, the **Camel Exchange properties are not propagated to routings** and they are removed together with the Exchange when the message reaches an end of the current route.

```
.setProperty("param1", header("param1")) // create property from header
.removeHeader("param1") // remove the header
```

This is a very explicit and transparent way to do this, but you have to do it everywhere you need it. So it is **good for exceptional cases that you want to make explicit**.

On the other hand a [HeaderFilterStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-avoid-sending-some-or-all-message-headers.html) prevents sending specific headers (based on patterns) to the endpoints you configure it. So it is **very good for general header rules** you want to apply to all endpoints of a specific type (for example to all HTTP endpoints).